# Creating a list to multiply columns

Tags: r, data.table

What I am trying to do is to get a list of stores then multiply those list of stores by a column called x-factor which will be the maximum for similar stores.

the list will come directly from a column called outlets.

```
Factors.out <- Metros[,list(n=NROW(Metros$outlet), XF=max(Metros$x_factor),
                      by=c("CategoryMnemonic","pno","metro_spaza"))]

Factors.out$Sum_XF <- Factors.out$n*Factors.out$XF
```

this is the error I get:

Error: Unsupported index type: list

[image]

so for store 000300 for instance then the code will aggregate the number of stores * maximum x_factor, then merge by the columns in the by clause.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example

Comment: A screen shot is not considered as [mcve].

Comment: Not sure what you require me to do?

Comment: Please, consider the answers to [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/3817004